# TiKZ generates unneeded whitespace

Tags: tikz-pgf

Edit: I did compile this document:

```
\documentclass[DIV14,parskip=half-]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\fbox{\begin{tikzpicture}
        \tkzDefPoint(0, 0){A}
        \tkzDefPoint(4, 0){B}
        \tkzDefPoint(6, 3.5){C}
        \tkzDefPoint(2, 3.5){D}
        \draw (0, 0) node[below left] {A} -- (4, 0) node[below right] {B} -- (6, 3.5) node[above right] {C} -- (2, 3.5) node[above left] {D} -- cycle;
        \tkzCircumCenter(A,B,D)
        \tkzGetPoint{O}
        \tkzDrawCircle(O,A)
        \tkzCircumCenter(A,C,D)
        \tkzGetPoint{O}
        \tkzDrawCircle(O,A)
\end{tikzpicture}}

\end{document}
```

and got this output:

[image: image of output]

With this code, TiKZ generates an image nearly twice as high as needed. Above the picture is a large whitespace. Where does it come from?

Original Code:

```
\documentclass[DIV14,parskip=half-]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0, 0) grid (10, 10);
        \tkzDefPoint(0, 0){A}
        \tkzDefPoint(4, 0){B}
        \tkzDefPoint(6, 3.5){C}
        \tkzDefPoint(2, 3.5){D}
        \draw (0, 0) node[below left] {A} -- (4, 0) node[below right] {B} -- (6, 3.5) node[above right] {C} -- (2, 3.5) node[above left] {D} -- cycle;
        \tkzCircumCenter(A,B,D)
        \tkzGetPoint{O}
        \tkzDrawCircle(O,A)
        \tkzCircumCenter(A,C,D)
        \tkzGetPoint{O}
        \tkzDrawCircle(O,A)
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Surround your `tikzpicture` with `\fbox{}` and put `\usepackage{showframe}` in your preamble. Like this you will see that there is no whitespace above your image. If it persists, update your TeX-Distribution or show us eventually missing code.

Comment: I don't see any spurious white space when I typeset the document on Ubuntu 12.04, with an added `preview` environment: http://cl.ly/Wk1m

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake: I did see some spurious whitespace at first and added the grid in ignorance of the fact that the grid itself is interpreted as part of the picture.

Comment: Still, there seems to be a problem to me. See updated question.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134718 http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130193

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The unneeded white space comes from the command `\tkzCircumCenter(...)`. An invisible path is used for the construction of the circle Center. It enlarges the bounding box.

You can patch this command using the package `etoolbox`

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\pretocmd\tkzCircumCenter{\begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}}{}{}
\apptocmd\tkzCircumCenter{\end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}}{}{}
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\pretocmd\tkzCircumCenter{\begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}}{}{}
\apptocmd\tkzCircumCenter{\end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}}{}{}

\begin{document}

\fbox{\begin{tikzpicture}
        \tkzDefPoint(0, 0){A}
        \tkzDefPoint(4, 0){B}
        \tkzDefPoint(6, 3.5){C}
        \tkzDefPoint(2, 3.5){D}
        \draw (0, 0) node[below left] {A} -- (4, 0) node[below right] {B} -- (6, 3.5) node[above right] {C} -- (2, 3.5) node[above left] {D} -- cycle;
        \tkzCircumCenter(A,B,D)
        \tkzGetPoint{O}
        \tkzDrawCircle(O,A)
        \tkzCircumCenter(A,C,D)
        \tkzGetPoint{O}
        \tkzDrawCircle(O,A)
\end{tikzpicture}}

\end{document}
```