# Tkz-euclide problem: figure layout is larger than the real picture

Tags: tkz-euclide, fit

When I use the tkz-euclide object (altitude and bisector) the figure layout is larger than the real picture dimension. How can I do to center and fit my images?

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{table, dvipsnames, svgnames, x11names}{xcolor}
\documentclass [a4paper,10pt]{book}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, intersections, plotmarks, matrix, quotes, angles, mindmap, arrows, folding, shapes, trees, hobby, backgrounds, positioning}
\usetkzobj{all}
\pgfkeys{/tikz/.cd, background color/.initial=lightgray!30, background color/.get=\backcol, background color/.store in=\backcol,}
\tikzset{background rectangle/.style={fill=\backcol,},use background/.style={show background rectangle}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\subfloat[][{\emph{Altitude}}]
{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1, x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm, use background]
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){A} \tkzDefPoint(4,0){B} \tkzDefPoint(1,3){C} \tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)
\tkzSetUpLine[color=blue] \tkzDrawAltitude(A,B)(C) \tkzGetPoint{H} \tkzMarkRightAngle(A,H,C) \tkzLabelPoints[below](A,B,H) \tkzLabelPoints[above](C)
\end{tikzpicture}}
\subfloat[][{\emph{Median}}]
{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm, use background]
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){A} \tkzDefPoint(4,0){B} \tkzDefPoint(1,3){C} \tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)
\tkzSetUpLine[color=red] \tkzDrawMedian(A,B)(C) \tkzGetPoint{M}
\tkzMarkSegments[mark=||](A,M M,B)
\tkzLabelPoints[below](A,B,M) \tkzLabelPoints[above](C)
\end{tikzpicture}}
\subfloat[][{\emph{Bisector}}]
{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1, x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm, use background]
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){A} \tkzDefPoint(4,0){B} \tkzDefPoint(1,3){C} \tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)
\tkzSetUpLine[color=Green] \tkzDrawBisector(A,C,B) \tkzGetPoint{D} \tkzMarkAngles[size=0.5cm, color=red,fill=purple, fill opacity=0.1, mark=|](A,C,D D,C,B)
\tkzLabelPoints[below](A,B,D) \tkzLabelPoints[above](C)
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A related question is [unnecessary white space in tikz picture after using \tkzInterLC[R]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130193/unnecessary-white-space-in-tikz-picture-after-using-tkzinterlcr/130209), and you can use the same strategy: place `\tkzDrawAltitude` and `\tkzDrawBisector` in a `pgfinterruptboundingbox` environment.

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{table, dvipsnames, svgnames, x11names}{xcolor}
\documentclass [a4paper,10pt]{book}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, intersections, plotmarks, matrix, quotes, angles, mindmap, arrows, folding, shapes, trees, hobby, backgrounds, positioning}
\usetkzobj{all}
\pgfkeys{/tikz/.cd, background color/.initial=lightgray!30, background color/.get=\backcol, background color/.store in=\backcol,}
\tikzset{background rectangle/.style={fill=\backcol,},use background/.style={show background rectangle}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\subfloat[][{\emph{Altitude}}]
{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1, x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm, use background]
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){A} \tkzDefPoint(4,0){B} \tkzDefPoint(1,3){C} \tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)
\tkzSetUpLine[color=blue] 
\begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
\tkzDrawAltitude(A,B)(C)
\end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
\tkzGetPoint{H} \tkzMarkRightAngle(A,H,C) \tkzLabelPoints[below](A,B,H) \tkzLabelPoints[above](C)

\end{tikzpicture}}
\subfloat[][{\emph{Median}}]
{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm, use background]
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){A} \tkzDefPoint(4,0){B} \tkzDefPoint(1,3){C} \tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)
\tkzSetUpLine[color=red] \tkzDrawMedian(A,B)(C) \tkzGetPoint{M}
\tkzMarkSegments[mark=||](A,M M,B)
\tkzLabelPoints[below](A,B,M) \tkzLabelPoints[above](C)
\end{tikzpicture}}
\subfloat[][{\emph{Bisector}}]
{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1, x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm, use background]
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){A} \tkzDefPoint(4,0){B} \tkzDefPoint(1,3){C} \tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)
\tkzSetUpLine[color=Green] 
\begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
\tkzDrawBisector(A,C,B)
\end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
\tkzGetPoint{D} \tkzMarkAngles[size=0.5cm, color=red,fill=purple, fill opacity=0.1, mark=|](A,C,D D,C,B)
\tkzLabelPoints[below](A,B,D) \tkzLabelPoints[above](C)
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `\subfloat` I would put the `tikzpicture` environments inside a `tabular` environment because I think that these are easier and cleaner to code. The downside of using `tabular` isa that you loose any indexing but as you have these diagrams inside a `figure` they will be indexed in the list of figures.

You can control the size of each `tikzpicture` using `\clip` to say how big you want each picture to be. By trial and error (certainly error on the first attempt!), I clipped to a rectangle with opposing vertices `(-0.2,-0.5)` and `(4.2,3.5)`.

Finally, I'd use `\tikzset` to define the specifications of each `tikzpicture` environment so that, if you need to, then you can tweak these settings in just one place.
[image]

Here's the code:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{table, dvipsnames, svgnames, x11names}{xcolor}
\documentclass [a4paper,10pt]{book}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, intersections, plotmarks, matrix, quotes, angles, mindmap, arrows, folding, shapes, trees, hobby, backgrounds, positioning}
\usetkzobj{all}
\pgfkeys{/tikz/.cd, background color/.initial=lightgray!30, background color/.get=\backcol, background color/.store in=\backcol,}
\tikzset{background rectangle/.style={fill=\backcol,},use background/.style={show background rectangle}}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{triangle/.style ={scale=1, use background, x=10mm, y=10mm}
}
\begin{figure}
  \begin{tabular}{ccc}
      \begin{tikzpicture}[triangle]
          \clip (-0.2,-0.5) rectangle (4.2,3.5);
          \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A} \tkzDefPoint(4,0){B} \tkzDefPoint(1,3){C}
          \tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)
          \tkzSetUpLine[color=blue] \tkzDrawAltitude(A,B)(C) \tkzGetPoint{H}
          \tkzMarkRightAngle(A,H,C) \tkzLabelPoints[below](A,B,H) \tkzLabelPoints[above](C)
      \end{tikzpicture}
      &
      \begin{tikzpicture}[triangle]
          \clip (-0.2,-0.5) rectangle (4.2,3.5);
          \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A} \tkzDefPoint(4,0){B} \tkzDefPoint(1,3){C} \tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)
          \tkzSetUpLine[color=red] \tkzDrawMedian(A,B)(C) \tkzGetPoint{M}
          \tkzMarkSegments[mark=||](A,M M,B)
          \tkzLabelPoints[below](A,B,M) \tkzLabelPoints[above](C)
      \end{tikzpicture}
      &
      \begin{tikzpicture}[triangle]
          \clip (-0.2,-0.5) rectangle (4.2,3.5);
          \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A} \tkzDefPoint(4,0){B} \tkzDefPoint(1,3){C}
          \tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C) \tkzSetUpLine[color=Green] \tkzDrawBisector(A,C,B)
          \tkzGetPoint{D}
          \tkzMarkAngles[size=0.5cm, color=red,fill=purple, fill opacity=0.1, mark=|](A,C,D D,C,B)
          \tkzLabelPoints[below](A,B,D) \tkzLabelPoints[above](C)
      \end{tikzpicture}
      \\[2mm]
      (a) \textit{Altitude} & (b) \textit{Median} & (c) \textit{Bisector}
  \end{tabular}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```