# The node is decentering my tikzpicture. Help please

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, horizontal-alignment

I am adding a node to a tikzpicture but it is decentering the figure on the slide. How can I fix this? Sorry. I did not find a similar Q&A here or elsewhere.

My example code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{,tikz,pgfplots}
\usetheme{default}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

    \begin{figure}
    \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
            xmin=-4,
            xmax=4,
            xlabel={\empty},
            ymin=0,
            ymax=0.5,
            xtick=\empty, 
            ytick=\empty,
            enlargelimits=false, 
            clip=false, 
            height=9cm, 
            width=13cm, 
            hide y axis,
            no markers,
            axis lines*=left,   
            ] 
            \addplot[color=black,domain=-4:4,samples=100] {1/sqrt(2*pi)*exp(-x^2/2)};
            \addplot+[color=black,fill= blue,mark=none,domain=1:2,samples=100,] {1/sqrt(2*pi)*exp(-x^2/2)} \closedcycle;
            \draw [red]  (axis cs:0,0) -- (axis cs:0,0.40);
            \node[below] at (axis cs:2.8, 0.4)  {VERY LONG TEXT HERE MOVES THE IMAGE}; 
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
    
\end{frame}
```

[image]

Comment: Probably you could make use of  pgfinterruptboundingbox as I did here : https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/565838/134144

Comment: `\node [overlay, below] ...`

Comment: Thanks Torbjorn. That did the trick. Solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
\node[draw,text width=3cm, font=\small] at (axis cs:2.8, 0.4)  {VERY LONG TEXT HERE MOVES THE IMAGE};
```

without the draw, without the rectangle.