# How to force an image to be always at the center of tikz environment?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have an image that is inserted into the text using tikzpicture environment.
I want to add some text and shapes to the left of the picture that is out of the picture's scope.
This action moves the picture to the right and the picture is not centered anymore.
How can I force the picture to be always horizontally aligned in tikzpicture environment?
I use these codes:

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[show grid]      \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{figures/airfoil.pdf}};
        \node (1)  at (-1,5) {SOME TEXT}; %by adding this, the picture is not aligned anymore
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: You could place the node containing the text inside of a `pgfinterruptedboundingbox` environment to hide it from the bounding box calculation, as for example shown here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/565838/134144 Please be aware that this might lead to the text protruding into the left margin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option `overlay` can be used (e.g. for `\node` or with the `scope` environment) to add stuff that is not used for the bounding box calculation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ribbonproofs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}[show grid]
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0)
      {\includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{example-image}};
    \begin{scope}[overlay]
      \node (1)  at (-1,5) {SOME TEXT};
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

> [image]