# How can I stop defined points that are not displayed from influencing image size?

Tags: tkz-euclide

I have the following image

[image]

that was created with this code:

```
\documentclass[varwidth=true, border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}
\usetkzobj{all}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzSetUpPoint[shape=circle,size=10,color=black,fill=black]
    \tkzSetUpLine[line width=1]
    \tkzDefPoints{0/0/A, 3/0/B', 2/2/C, 4/4/C'}
    \tkzDefLine[parallel=through C](B',C') \tkzGetPoint{Phelper}
    \tkzInterLL(A,B')(C,Phelper) \tkzGetPoint{B}
    \tkzDrawLine[add=0 and 0.2](A,B')
    \tkzDrawLine[add=0 and 0.2](A,C')
    \tkzDrawSegment(B',C')

    \node at ($(A)+(-0.1,-0.2)$)  {$A$};
    \node at ($(B')+(0.2,-0.2)$)  {$B'$};
    \node at ($(C')+(0,0.4)$)  {$C'$};
    \node at ($(B)+(0.2,-0.2)$)  {$B$};
    \node at ($(C)+(0.28,0.5)$)  {$C$};
    \tkzDrawPolygon[ultra thick,color=blue,fill=blue!20](A,B',C') 
    \tkzDrawPolygon[line width=0.3pt,color=red,fill=red!20](A,B,C) 
    \tkzDrawPoints(A,B',C',B,C)
    \tkzLabelSegment[below,red](A,B){$c$}
    \tkzLabelSegment[left,red](A,C){$b$}
    \tkzLabelSegment[right,red](B,C){$a$}
    \tkzLabelSegment[below,blue,pos=0.8](A,B'){$c'$}
    \tkzLabelSegment[left,blue,pos=0.8](A,C'){$b'$}
    \tkzLabelSegment[right,blue](B',C'){$a'$}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As you might notice, the space above `C'` is bigger than necessary. This is because of `Phelper`. I need `Phelper` for the construction, but it should not influence the image size in any way. I've tried to get `Phelper` closer to `C`, but that seems not to be possible.

**How can I stop defined (but not visible) points from influencing image size?**

Please note:
I wrap code like this in a figure. So images like the one above are only a part of the whole document. So working with `standalone` does not solve my problem.

Comment: You can use the `pgfinterruptboundingbox` environment as in e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130193 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23332 Place the line defining `Phelper` in this environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the key `/tikz/overlay` to the command that defines the coordinate `Phelpher` (which is actually the `\tkzDefLine` command).  This key says "Don't use this construction when computing the bounding box.".  It's the single-key version of `pgfinterruptboundingbox` that Torbjørn refers to in his comment.  As `tkz` macros use their own keys, and don't pass unknown keys on to tikz, you need the `/tikz/` prefix.

```
\documentclass[varwidth=true, border=2pt]{standalone}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/155343/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}
\usetkzobj{all}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzSetUpPoint[shape=circle,size=10,color=black,fill=black]
    \tkzSetUpLine[line width=1]
    \tkzDefPoints{0/0/A, 3/0/B', 2/2/C, 4/4/C'}
    \tkzDefLine[parallel=through C,/tikz/overlay](B',C') \tkzGetPoint{Phelper}
    \tkzInterLL(A,B')(C,Phelper) \tkzGetPoint{B}
    \tkzDrawLine[add=0 and 0.2](A,B')
    \tkzDrawLine[add=0 and 0.2](A,C')
    \tkzDrawSegment(B',C')

    \node at ($(A)+(-0.1,-0.2)$)  {$A$};
    \node at ($(B')+(0.2,-0.2)$)  {$B'$};
    \node at ($(C')+(0,0.4)$)  {$C'$};
    \node at ($(B)+(0.2,-0.2)$)  {$B$};
    \node at ($(C)+(0.28,0.5)$)  {$C$};
    \tkzDrawPolygon[ultra thick,color=blue,fill=blue!20](A,B',C') 
    \tkzDrawPolygon[line width=0.3pt,color=red,fill=red!20](A,B,C) 
    \tkzDrawPoints(A,B',C',B,C)
    \tkzLabelSegment[below,red](A,B){$c$}
    \tkzLabelSegment[left,red](A,C){$b$}
    \tkzLabelSegment[right,red](B,C){$a$}
    \tkzLabelSegment[below,blue,pos=0.8](A,B'){$c'$}
    \tkzLabelSegment[left,blue,pos=0.8](A,C'){$b'$}
    \tkzLabelSegment[right,blue](B',C'){$a'$}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: before and after shots]